# QSpatiaLite Plugin: LINESTRINGZ(x y z, ...) supported?

Tags: qgis, linestring, qspatialite

I get an error when trying to import this query as a spatial table in QGIS:

```
select geomFromText('LINESTRING Z(13.091464 47.061328 2597, 13.092059 47.061287 2580)') as geometry
```

> 'The result can't be loaded in QGIS..'

However, the results-panel of the QSpatiaLite Plugin shows a column with a valid 'GeomObject'

Does anybody know what's the problem here?

[image]

Comment: Can you show the schema for the table you're trying to import this into? In particular, can you tell us if there is a SRID set on it?

Comment: Nope, no SRID. I just use the 'Load in QGIS as Spatial Table' function, and run the query.. Usually, with a working dataset, I'm then asked to choose a CRS and the table would be loaded to QGIS properly. Please, also see the screenshot added to the OP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The z-value is not supported in QGIS. Removing the z-value and changing WKT to LINESTRING makes the SQL load in QGIS.

```
select geomFromText('LINESTRING(13.091464 47.061328, 13.092059 47.061287)') as geometry
```

Why do you want the two z-values 2597 and 2580 into QGIS?

Comment: I tried both 'LINESTRING Z' and 'LINESTRINGZ' and both return a GeomObject (so I suppose that's fine)! Where did you take the '1' and '2' after the altitude value from? I never used those in the original posting. HOwever, your proposed SQL with 'LINESTRING()' without the 'Z' returns a NULL, so I suppose this does not work. Have you tried this with QSpatiaLite?

Comment: I updated the answer

Comment: So you actually don't know it either? I need the z-values because I want to export to kml, with linestrings including altitude-values..

Comment: 3D geometry is not supported in QGIS

Comment: Thanks. Replace "Looks like" with "is not supported" in your answer and I'll check it..

Comment: However, it should be noted that with the GRASS plugin 3D geometries work in QGIS..